# Confirmation that a postgres 'update' query worked in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I've written my first 'update' query in python, while it seems correct, I'm not sure how to receive back the output to confirm it worked..

This is supposed to load a CSV file and replace the values in the first column with those in the second:

```
def main():
    try:
        conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='subs' user='subs' host='localhost' password=''")
    except:
        print "I am unable to connect to the database."
        sys.exit()

    with open("dne.txt", "r+") as f:
        for line in f:
            old = line.split(',')[0].strip()
            new = line.split(',')[1].strip()
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("UPDATE master_list SET subs = '{0}' WHERE subs = '{1}';".format(new, old))
            conn.commit()
            results = cur.fetchall()
            for each in results:
                print str(each)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I thought the results (UPDATE 1 for each change?) would come back as a tuple, but I got an error instead:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
```

I'm not sure if this means my query just didn't work and there were no updates, or if I can't use fetchall() like I'm trying to.

Any feedback or suggestions welcome!

Comment: have you tried commit your data before fetching? I mean cur.commit() I'm not sure if it's useful in your case but sometimes not commiting is the problem.

Comment: @ Lafexlos -     cur.commit()
AttributeError: 'psycopg2._psycopg.cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: ah sorry. I meant conn.commit(). darn typos.

Comment: no problem. unfortunately, that gave the same error as the original post

Comment: one more line of code. cur.execute(select * from table_name) than results = cur.fetchall()

Comment: that "worked..."  As in, it listed everything in the table when the script was run. But -- the table is around 15k entries, so listing everything is not ideal. That being said, it did show that the updates did NOT change, so something else is definitely wrong here.

Comment: Did you try `RETURNING` by any chance? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The UPDATE statement won't return any values as you are asking the database to update its data not to retrieve any data.

By far the best way to get the number of rows updated is to use cur.rowcount. This works with other drivers too, like with Psycopg2 for Postgresql it's the same syntax.

```
cur.execute("UPDATE master SET sub = ('xyz') WHERE sub = 'abc'")
print(cur.rowcount)
```

A more roundabout way of checking the update is by running a SELECT against the table after updating it; you should get the data returned. In my example below the first SELECT will return the row(s) where the update will happen. The second SELECT after the update should then return no rows as you have already updated all fields. The third SELECT should return the rows you have updated, plus any that already existed with the 'xyz' value.

```
import sqlite3

def main():
    try:
        conn=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("create table master(id text, sub text)")
        cur.execute("insert into master(id, sub) values ('1', 'abc')")
        cur.execute("insert into master(id, sub) values ('2', 'def')")
        cur.execute("insert into master(id, sub) values ('3', 'ghi')")
        conn.commit()
    except:
        print("I am unable to connect to the database.")
        sys.exit()

    cur.execute("select id, sub from master where sub='abc'")
    print(cur.fetchall())
    cur.execute("UPDATE master SET sub = ('xyz') WHERE sub = 'abc'")
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("select id, sub from master where sub='abc'")
    print(cur.fetchall())
    cur.execute("select id, sub from master where sub='xyz'")
    print(cur.fetchall())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks. so there is no way to get a direct response back after performing an update query?

Comment: For sqlite there is a "rowcount" attribute on the cursor which records the number of affected rows from the last update: print(cur.rowcount) This seems to be true for Postgres as well

Comment: adding in the the print(cur.rowcount) basically did it, it printed "1" 48 times, which was the number of rows in the csv file.

Comment: @leancz cur.rowcount is a far better answer, you should formulate it that way in your main message. Way faster than another select. It works with other drivers too, like with Psycopg2 for Postgresql it's the same syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL 9.5 or later you can add `RETURNING *` to end your query that then returns the modified rows.

PostgreSQL docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/dml-returning.html

> Sometimes it is useful to obtain data from modified rows while they
> are being manipulated. The INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE commands all
> have an optional RETURNING clause that supports this. Use of RETURNING
> avoids performing an extra database query to collect the data, and is
> especially valuable when it would otherwise be difficult to identify
> the modified rows reliably.